# How to merge two count values using one expression with lambda?

Tags: python, arrays, lambda, count, apply

**In this small dataframe:**

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('to_count.mcve.txt', sep='\t')

pos   M1          M2      F1    F2
23    A,B,A,C,D   A,C,B   A     D
24    A,B,B,C,B   A,B,A   B     D
28    C,B,C,D,E   B,C     E     D
```

I want to count **how many of the values in F1 and F2 are in M1 and M2**. As, a learning process I have broken it down into pieces.

I can do:

```
d1_count = d1.apply(lambda x: x.loc[::].str.count(x.F1), 1)
```

Output:

```
        M1  M2  F1  F2
   pos                
 0 23    2   1   1   0
 1 24    3   1   1   1
 2 28    1   0   1   0
```

And, similarly

```
d2_count = d1.apply(lambda x: x.loc[::].str.count(x.F2), 1)
```

with output:

```
       M1  M2  F1  F2
  pos                
0 23    1   0   0   1
1 24    3   1   1   1
2 28    2   1   0   1
```

**But, I want the following Final Expected output:**

I want to count both F1 and F2 in one line and the output to put F1 values separated by F2 with comma

We can leave F1 and F2 out by dropping which isn't a big issue.

```
         M1    M2    
   pos                
 0 23    2,1   1,0   
 1 24    3,3   1,1  
 2 28    1,2   0,1
```

I tried to use join but failed, and then append (which din't work as I exactly expected):

```
d3_count = d1.apply(lambda x: x.loc[::].str.count(x.F1).append(x.loc[::].str.count(x.F2)), 1)

       M1  M2  F1  F2  M1  M2  F1  F2
  pos                                
0 23    2   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
1 24    3   1   1   1   3   1   1   1
2 28    1   0   1   0   2   1   0   1
```

Any inputs with explanation please.

Thanks,

Comment: How did you get `3,3   1,1`? Isn't it supposed to be `3,1   0,0` or `3,0   1,0`?

Comment: Oops that should have been a typo. I will have to correct it

Comment: @DYZ: Actually there is not typo. I just updated the ouput from the counts of **F1 and F2** to make the question more clear. Can you please have a look?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I still believe your result `d2_count` is wrong: there are no Ds in M2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would o this; first, make `pos` the index to eliminate it from all further operations:

```
d1.set_index('pos', inplace=True)
```

You cat `reset_index()` later if you want. Now, find the counts, convert them to strings, and "add":

```
d1.apply(lambda x: x[['M1','M2']].str.count(x.F1), 1).astype('str') +\
"," +\
d1.apply(lambda x: x[['M1','M2']].str.count(x.F2), 1).astype('str')
#      M1   M2
#pos          
#23   2,1  1,0
#24   3,0  1,0
#28   1,1  0,0
```

Comment: Such a easy way to do it, but I couldn't think about it **as str**. Thanks much.